# how to change iframe src from inside it

Tags: javascript, html

I need to change src attribute of iframe after click a button inside the iframe.

```
<button type="button" onclick="ch_src('page2.php')">Submit</button>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function ch_src(loc) 
{ 
var v = document.getElementById('iframe1');
v.src = loc;
}
</script>
```

(1) when using `window.location = loc;` it changes the content of iframe but src still pointing to previous page. 
(2) why we need to change src value not only open the new page inside iframe? we use JS to print iframe content excluding content outside iframe. this script is printing page in src not actual opened page. 
(3) above function can't change src mostly coz it can't get element id of itself (iframe) but may be sub elements. 
(4) when moving the function outside the iframe, it doesn't execute. may be due to "same origin policy"

finally we need to click a button in (page1.php) inside iframe causes 
(1) load (page2.php) into same iframe 
(2) change iframe's src attribute to (page2.php)

Answer (score 0):

first include jquery
then
try this in you page1.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("iframe").load(function(){
      $(this).contents().find("button").click(function(){
      document.querySelectorAll("iframe").src = "https://example.com/page2.php";
      });
  });
});
</script>
```

for better detection please paste your page1.php here